# Can I move the /boot/efi and the swap partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, multi-boot, dualboot

I have a Manjaro/Windows 11 dual boot going on, but it seems I haven't allocated much space for the root filesystem (~25GB) and now it's warning me of low disk space, so I need to expand root space.

I tried to use GParted Live with an USB stick and shrink the Windows partition, but I realized my `boot/efi` and `swap` partitions stand between the Windows partition and the root partition, so I can't use the unallocated space that's to the left of them.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Can i move them around safely or should I just reinstall Manjaro?

Answer (score 1):

Swap can be disabled, deleted, re-created where you want it (mkswap), and re-enabled. Make sure to update your /etc/fstab with the new UUID if it had any mentions of the old partition.

The EFI partition can be moved, or re-created, as long as it retains its partition GUID... and preferably its position in the list, otherwise Windows seems to get a little confused. I'd usually suggest re-creating it.

In your case, it looks like the ESP is the 1st partition, not the 7th, so I don't really see any need to move it at all. If you have two ESPs (one for Windows, one for Linux), you can move the Linux one.

(To re-create an ESP, use `partx` to note the old GUID, tarball/zip all files, delete and re-create the partition in the new place, extract all files, use `fdisk` or `gdisk` "expert" submenu to restore the same GUID.)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to *move* a partition is *always* risky, particularly one at the beginning. You can minimize the risk by making a **full drive image**, so you can revert from a disaster. **Verify** the image. Then you can experiment with a bit more confidence.

However, I'd just shrink Windows and reinstall Linux after it. Loss of 25 GB on a 500 GB driver is negligible (~5%), or you could reallocate that space for other use. Personally, I'd keep the Windows NTFS together, rather than stick the ext4 partitions in between. Also, you might consider eliminating the swap *partition* and [using a swap *file*](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Swap), which is more flexible to change, should you add RAM or want to test a different size.